Power automate - apply to each to fill missing values
I have an array like below:
  {“Field”:”abc”,
    “Modifiedby”:null
    },
   {
    “Field”:”abc”,
    “Modifiedby”:null
    },
   {
    “Field”:”abc”,
    “Modifiedby”:”Dave”
    },
   {
    “Field”:”abc”,
    “Modifiedby”:null
    },
   {
    “Field”:”abc”,
    “Modifiedby”:”Matt”
    }

I want to fill the null values with the next item that's not null. So the first 2 will have Dave and the 4th will have Matt in Modifiedby column.
What's an efficient way to achieve this? Thanks.
